# Start new activity on orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

I want to load a new activity when the orientation changes from potrait to landscape for which I am using:

```
@Override
public  void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ABCDActivity.class));
    }

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        finish();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change my activity with the change in orientation. Have I missed something?

Comment: Refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983792/how-to-switch-to-other-activity-at-orientation-change-and-then-back-again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onConfigurationChanged() method will not be called unless you declared the respective attributes under the  in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
      {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, ABCDActivity.class));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Manifest` `Activity` tag for each activity you wish to configChanges for, you must place this line:

> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

As an app design note... Starting a new activity on orientation change is not advised...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to start a new Activity when your orientation changed?
It's better to just provide different resources for different configurations! Or use Fragments inside 1 Activity.

More information can be found here:

- [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

EDIT:
You can just create one activity that recreates itself on orientation change. So remove any `configChanges="screenSize..."` you have in your AndroidManifest.xml.
In the xml files for the activity, you can just link to another Fragment.
And again, more information about this can be found in the above links.

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle cycle)
 {
    super.onCreate(cycle);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
 }
}
```

res/layout/myactivity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment 
        class="com.example.myapp.fragments.TimeFrameGraphFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And res/layout-land/myactivity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment 
        class="com.example.myapp.fragments.AllDataGraphFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I am showing data(in a graph) for specific time interval while in portrait mode but  I want to display all the data when the user switches to Landscape.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for the built-in Resource System using layout/ and layout-land/ folders. I updated my answer with some example code. Please accept it if it helped you out.